# Knockoutjs: Checkbox list many to many Relation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a Knockout model that have created in the snippet below.

What I'm trying to do is create a many to many relationship in a popup dialog from option rows that ive added to a option(I'm hoping this make sense when you look at the jsfiddler). When you click on the lookup link on the children column on the rows I list ALL the option rows in a dialog and with a check box list and allow the user to select the children relations to the to a specific row, hence a many to many relationship between rows.

I have defaulted the data of of my desired as a output in the first option group but I am not sure how to make this work.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this correct way and am hoping some Knockout guru can point me in the right direction to get this functionality in the popup.

```js
/*Select Options*/
var initialData = [{
    title: "User Band",
    productoptionrows: [{
        id: "1",
        title: "25-100",
        related: [{
            id: "4",
            title: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "5",
            title: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "6",
            title: '3 Year'
        }]
    }, {
        id: "2",
        title: "101-250",
        related: [{
            id: "7",
            title: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "8",
            title: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "9",
            title: 'qwe'
        }]
    }, {
        id: "3",
        title: "251-500",
        related: [{
            id: "10",
            title: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "11",
            title: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "12",
            title: '3 Year'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    title: "Please select the number of years license",
    productoptionrows: [{
        id: "4",
        title: "1 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "5",
        title: "2 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "6",
        title: "3 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "7",
        title: "1 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "8",
        title: "2 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "9",
        title: "3 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "10",
        title: "1 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "11",
        title: "2 Year",
        related: []
    }, {
        id: "12",
        title: "3 Year",
        related: []
    }]
}];


$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Models*/
    var mappingOptions = {
        'productoptionrows': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new productoptionrow(options.data);
            }
        }
    };
    var mappingOptionsPR = {
        create: function (options) {
            return new productoptionrow(options.data);
        }
    };
    var productoptionrow = function (por) {
        var self = ko.mapping.fromJS(por, {}, this);
        self.relatedcsv = ko.computed(function () {
            return $(por.related).map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }).get().join(',');
        }, self);
        self.selectedrelated = ko.observableArray($(por.related).map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get());
    };
    var ProductOptionModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.productoptions = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
        self.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedrelated = ko.observableArray([]);
        /*Control Events*/
        self.addProductOption = function () {
            var newoption = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                title: "Please select the number of years license",
                productoptionrows: ko.observableArray([{
                    id: "15",
                    title: "25-100",
                    related: []
                }, {
                    id: "16",
                    title: "101-250",
                    related: []
                }, {
                    id: "17",
                    title: "251-500",
                    related: []
                }])
            }, mappingOptions);
            self.productoptions.push(newoption);
        };
        self.copyProductOption = function (productoption) {
            var copy = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(productoption), mappingOptions);
            self.productoptions.push(copy);
        };
        self.removeProductOption = function (productoption) {
            self.productoptions.remove(productoption);
        };
        self.addProductOptionRow = function (productoption) {
            var newrow = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                id: "15",
                title: "25-100",
                related: []
            }, mappingOptionsPR);
            productoption.productoptionrows.push(newrow);
        };
        self.removeProductOptionRow = function (productoption) {
            $.each(self.productoptions(), function () {
                this.productoptionrows.remove(productoption)
            })
        };
        self.open = function (productoption, event) {
            self.selectedrelated(productoption.related);
            self.isOpen(true);
        };
        self.close = function () {
            self.isOpen(false);
        }
        self.associaterelated = function (record, elem) {
            //console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(record));
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ProductOptionModel(initialData), document.getElementById('page-wrapper'));

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/gvas/knockout-jqueryui/075b303a/dist/knockout-jqueryui.min.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>
    <button title="Add Option" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.addProductOption'>Add Option</button>
  </div>
  <div id="options" data-bind="foreach: productoptions">
    <div style="padding:10px;margin:20px;background-color:whitesmoke">
      <table class="option-header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Group Title <span class="required">*</span></th>
            <th>
              <button title="Copy" type="button" class="" style="" data-bind='click: $root.copyProductOption'>Copy</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button title="Delete Option" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.removeProductOption'>Delete Option</button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr style="height:36px;">
            <td>
              <input type="text" data-bind='value: title'>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <table class="option-header-rows" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
              <th>Id</th>
              <th colspan="2" class="type-title">Title <span class="required">*</span></th>         
              <th>Children</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: productoptionrows">
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <input required type="text" style="width:40px" data-bind='value: id'>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" value="25-100" data-bind='value: title'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind='value: relatedcsv' name="isdefault"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.open, disable: $root.isOpen">Lookup</a></td>
              <td>
                <button title="Delete Row" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.removeProductOptionRow'>Delete Row</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <button title="Add New Row" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.addProductOptionRow'>Add New Row</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- popup -->
  <div data-bind="dialog: { isOpen: isOpen,title:'Select relations', modal:true }">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $root.productoptions">
      <div data-bind='text: title'></div>
      <div data-bind="foreach: productoptionrows">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id, checked: $root.selectedrelated" style="width:auto" />
          ID <span data-bind='text: id'></span> - <span data-bind='text: title'></span> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the popup should do. Add the checked licenses to all checked User Bands? Or only to the one you clicked? You might want to trim away some of the data and additional properties so we can focus on the part that you can't get to work...

Comment: @user3297291 What im trying to do is relate the year options to each user band, I have default desired output each user band with the corresponding ID of the year option. 

Eg.
Userband 25-100 The user should be able to check IDs 4,5,6
Userband 101-250 The user should be able to check IDs 7,8,9
Userband 251-500 The user should be able to check IDs 10,11,12

Then in the children textbox of each Userband you can see the IDs of the corresponding Years.

When i click on a user band popup I would expect the year option already check as above

Comment: What is the significance of the Groups?  It looks like they are all created the same way. Can any item in one Group map to any item in any other Group? Can an item map to items in its own Group? Can it map to itself? If item A maps to item B, does that mean item B also maps to item A?

Comment: @ Roy J, Any item in one group can map to any item in another group.

The behavior im looking for is:

When you click on "lookup button" in the row of Id1, then the popup should display all the options as it currently does but also check the boxes with IDs 4,5,6 as thats the children of Id1. The popup should allow you to change the children.

I think the problem I'm having in the popup, is i'm trying to link seperate arrays. Its not a standard many to many but relating items in separate arrays to each other. I'm just note sure how to structure the viewmodel/data to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to distill the many-to-many issue down to a simple example. Here, persons and things are mapped to each other. To track the mapping, each person has a list of things. For each possible thing, there is a checkbox with that value. Its `checked` binding is bound to the thingList for the current person.

Binding to an array makes the checkbox insert or remove its value to/from the array.

```js
function person(name) {
  return {
    name,
    thingList: ko.observableArray()
  };
}

const vm = {
  people: ko.observableArray(['Abby', 'Bill', 'Charlie'].map((n) => person(n))),
  things: ko.observableArray(['apple', 'bullet', 'cup', 'doll', 'egg'])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.checklist {
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.no-bullets li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:people">
  <div>Name: <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    <div class="checklist" data-bind="foreach:$parent.things">
      <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="value:$data, checked:$parent.thingList"><span data-bind="text:$data"></span></label>
    </div>
    <ul class="no-bullets" data-bind="foreach:thingList"><li data-bind="text:$data"></li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy,

Thank you for posting a update on how you work with many to many relationship.

The problem I'm having is working out how to do a self referencing many to many relationship. I have reduced my original example but i am unable to get this working.